# What would be the easiest approach towards parsing this xml file into the specified JSON with Java?

Tags: xml, parsing

The body and abstract are made up of an array of paragraphs, and each paragraph can have in-line citations. I am mostly worried about the information contained within the paragraph. The citations I can leave empty for now. One more thing, each paragraph can belong to 1 main section and to multiple subsections.

I was asked to implement the subsection hierarchy as "subsection1.subsection2.subsection3" which states the hierarchy by separating the subsections with dots. I was first thinking of using XOM to parse the xml into a POJO, and then use GSON to serialize it into JSON. Is there an easier approach to take?

[XML](https://pastebin.com/yBnmd7a6) (it's kind of long)

JSON schema of full text documents

```
{
    "paper_id": <str>,                      # 40-character sha1 of the PDF
    "metadata": {
        "title": <str>,
        "authors": [                        # list of author dicts, in order
            {
                "first": <str>,
                "middle": <list of str>,
                "last": <str>,
                "suffix": <str>,
                "affiliation": <dict>,
                "email": <str>
            },
            ...
        ],
        "abstract": [                       # list of paragraphs in the abstract
            {
                "text": <str>,
                "cite_spans": [             # list of character indices of inline citations
                                            # e.g. citation "[7]" occurs at positions 151-154 in "text"
                                            #      linked to bibliography entry BIBREF3
                    {
                        "start": 151,
                        "end": 154,
                        "text": "[7]",
                        "ref_id": "BIBREF3"
                    },
                    ...
                ],
                "ref_spans": <list of dicts similar to cite_spans>,     # e.g. inline reference to "Table 1"
                "section": "Abstract"
            },
            ...
        ],
        "body_text": [                      # list of paragraphs in full body
                                            # paragraph dicts look the same as above
            {
                "text": <str>,
                "cite_spans": [],
                "ref_spans": [],
                "eq_spans": [],
                "section": "Introduction"
            },
            ...
            {
                ...,
                "section": "Conclusion"
            }
        ],
        "bib_entries": {
            "BIBREF0": {
                "ref_id": <str>,
                "title": <str>,
                "authors": <list of dict>       # same structure as earlier,
                                                # but without `affiliation` or `email`
                "year": <int>,
                "venue": <str>,
                "volume": <str>,
                "issn": <str>,
                "pages": <str>,
                "other_ids": {
                    "DOI": [
                        <str>
                    ]
                }
            },
            "BIBREF1": {},
            ...
            "BIBREF25": {}
        },
        "ref_entries":
            "FIGREF0": {
                "text": <str>,                  # figure caption text
                "type": "figure"
            },
            ...
            "TABREF13": {
                "text": <str>,                  # table caption text
                "type": "table"
            }
        },
        "back_matter": <list of dict>           # same structure as body_text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Easiest" depends rather a lot on your skill set.

I would do it using XSLT 3.0. There are several ways you can approach the task in XSLT 3.0; I think I would do it with template rules that construct maps and arrays, and then use the JSON serialization method to convert the resulting structure of maps and arrays to JSON. Here are two of the template rules you might use, as a sample:

```
<xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="tei:biblStruct/tei:analytic">
  <xsl:map:entry key="'authors'" select="f:array-from(tei:author)"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tei:author">
  <xsl:map>
    <xsl:if test="tei:persName/tei:firstName">
       <xsl:map:entry key="'first'" select="string(tei:persName/tei:firstName)"/>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="tei:persName/tei:lastName">
       <xsl:map:entry key="'last'" select="string(tei:persName/tei:lastName)"/>
    </xsl:if>
    ...
</xsl:template>
```

The lack of an `xsl:array` instruction for constructing arrays is unfortunate. If you're using Saxon-PE or higher you can use the `saxon:array` extension instruction which fills this gap, but you can also work around the limitation by writing your own function as follows (you only need to do this once):

```
<xsl:function name="f:array-from" as="array(*)">
  <xsl:param name="elements" select="element(*)*"/>
  <xsl:variable name="out" as="item()*">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$elements"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:sequence select="array{$out}"/>
</xsl:function>
```

Comment: I've never heard of XSLT before. I will look for some tutorial on it. It seems to be straightforward though.

Comment: I suppose that going xml->html->JSON is easier than going xml->POJO->json?

Comment: The XSLT approach goes from XML to JSON directly rather than going through an intermediate form (HTML or Java) and I think that makes it simpler. XSLT does have a learning curve - but it should be a standard part of every XML practitioner's toolkit.

Comment: Hello. I ended up going for XOM for the first version since I've used it before. For second release I will use XSLT. Thank you for the valuable information.

Comment: That's fine. Using XOM rather than DOM is an excellent choice, I wish more people would realise that there are much better alternatives to DOM.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your quick replies.